# MongoDB Geospatial, project matching multi points

Tags: php, mongodb, geospatial, mongodb-geospatial

Via MongoDB $geoNear command with Aggregate, I'm unable to generate locations that are within the queried maxDistance field.

```
        array(
            '$geoNear'          => array(
                'near'             => array(
                    'type'            => "MultiPoint",
                    'coordinates'     => [ 
                        $city["geo"]["coordinates"][0], 
                        $city["geo"]["coordinates"][1] 
                    ],
                ),
                "distanceField"    => "distance",
                "maxDistance"      => 1*1609.34,
                "includeLocs"      => "locations",
                "spherical"        => true,
                "query" => array(
                    "status" => true
                ),
                "limit" => 500
            ),
        ),
```

The documentation states to use includeLocs "*specifies the output field that identifies the location used to calculate the distance. This option is useful when a location field contains multiple locations*.", however the includeLocs field is including all multipoint locations.

Does mongodb have the ability to project only the matching multipoints and not the whole set stored?

Comment: I think you need a library like [GeoPHP](https://geophp.net/api.html#user-content-methods-2), I guess `union` is the method to use.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit rather using a library I can just run a distance calculation on each coordinate, but I assume MongoDB's "includeLocs" would return the specifics... the documentation is a bit vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this:

1. After the $geoNear pipeline, add an $unwind stage to unwind the "includeLocs" array i.e. {$unwind: '$locations.coordinates'} (Make sure you unwind the coordinates).
2. Add another stage for '$match' with the $geoWithin geospatial operator with the field marked specifically to the unwinded coordinates field i.e. '$locations.coordinates'.
3. Finally add a '$group' stage to join everything back to the _id field.